# MySQL joins to display categories, subcategories and subsubcategories

Tags: sql, mysql

I have three tables: categories, subcategories and subsubcategories.

I want to display a list that's formatted like:

```
dvds
cds
cds > pop
cds > blues
cds > new age
cds > new age > whale noises
books
books > cowboys
books > zombies
```

I've managed to display everything except for the names of categories on their own when they have children, eg what I'm getting is:

```
dvds
cds > pop
cds > blues
cds > new age > whale noises
books > cowboys
books > zombies
```

The above list is missing the cds and books categories, plus the cds > new age subcategory.

The query I'm using is:

```
SELECT
  c.name AS c_name,
  sc.name AS sc_name,
  ssc.name AS ssc_name
FROM
  categories c
LEFT JOIN
  subcategories sc
  ON c.id = sc.category_id
LEFT JOIN
  subsubcategories ssc
  ON sc.id = ssc.subcategory_id
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT
                c.name AS c_name,
                sc.name AS sc_name,
                ssc.name AS ssc_name
        FROM    categories c
        LEFT JOIN
                subcategories sc
        ON      c.id = sc.category_id
        LEFT JOIN
                subsubcategories ssc
        ON      sc.id = ssc.subcategory_id
        GROUP BY
                c.name, sc.name, ssc.name WITH ROLLUP
        HAVING  c_name IS NOT NULL
        ) q
ORDER BY
        c_name, sc_name, ssc_name
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That's almost right except it's displaying category_name twice for categories with no children. Categories with subcategories and subsubcategories are working prefectly though.

Comment: Oh wait, no they're not working perfectly. They're displaying as cds > whale noises and cds > new age > whale noises, instead of cds > new age and cds > new age > whale noises.

Comment: Almost there! It's got rid of the duplicates but it's still displaying as cds > whale noises & cds > new age > whale noises, instead of cds > new age & cds > new age > whale noises.

I really appreciate your help so far!

Comment: @Dan: just checked on your very data, got `cds > new age`, `cds > new age > whale noises`. Could you please post the dump of your tables here?

Comment: Oh sorry, you're completely right. I'd missed out the ssc.name in the group by, it's working absolutely perfectly now. Thanks for all your help :)